# The set consisting of all solutions of a homogeneous linear differential equation of order $n$ is a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

The set $S$ consisting of all solutions of a homogeneous linear differential equation of order $n$ is a vector space.

Comment: Indeed, it is. So what?

Answer (score 3):

Let 
$$
{\mathcal L}x=x^{(n)}+a_{n-1}(t)x^{(n-1)}+\cdots+a_0(t)x,
$$
where $a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1}: I\to\mathbb R$ continuous, and $I$ an open interval. If $\tau\in I$ and $\varphi_j$, $j=1,\ldots,n$, the solution of the initial value problem
$$
{\mathcal L}x=0, \quad x^{(i-1)}(\tau)=\delta_{ij}, \,\,i=1,\ldots,n,
$$
then $\{\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n\}$ is a basis of the solution space 
$X=\{\psi\in C^n(I):{\mathcal L}\psi=0\}$, and hence, $X$ is an $n-$dimensional subspace of $C^n(I)$.

In order to show this, one needs to establish two facts. First, the $\varphi_j$'s span $X$. Second, the $\varphi_j$'s are linearly independent.

1. Clearly, if $\psi\in X$, then $\psi$ satisfies the IVP 
   $$
   {\mathcal L}x=0, \quad x^{(i-1)}(\tau)=\psi^{(i-1)}(\tau), \,\,i=1,\ldots,n, \qquad (\star)
   $$
   and so does
   $$
   \zeta(t)=\sum_{j=1}^n \psi^{(j-1)}(\tau)\,\varphi_j(t),
   $$
   and by uniqueness of solutions of $(\star)$ we have that 
   $$
   \psi=\zeta=\sum_{j=1}^n \psi^{(j-1)}(\tau)\,\varphi_j \in\mathrm{span}\{\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n\}.
   $$
2. If $c_1\varphi_1+\cdots+c_n\varphi \equiv 0$, then does vanish its $(j-1)-$derivative at $t=\tau$, which is equal to $c_j$.

Answer (score 1):

All solutions of a homogeneous linear ordinary differential equations of order $n$ can be written as a linear combination of $n$ linearly independent solutions of that equation. It is thus a vector space spanned by these $n$ functions over the field of the real numbers.